# R describeby function subscript out of bounds error

Tags: r, psych

I'm fairly new to R and I'm trying to get descriptive statistics grouped by multiple variables using the describeby function from the psych package.

Here's what I'm trying to run:

```
JL <- describeBy(df$JL, group=list(df$Time, df$Cohort, df$Gender), digits=3, skew=FALSE, mat=TRUE)
```

And I get the error message `` Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, var, group + 1, value = dim.names[[group]][[groupi]]) : 
  subscript out of bounds ``

I only get this error message with my Gender variable (which is dichotomous in this datset). I'm able to run the code when I take out the mat=TRUE argument, and I see that it's generating groupings with NULL for Gender. I saw in other answers that this has something to do with the array being out of bounds but I'm not sure how to troubleshoot. Any advice is appreciated.

Thanks so much.

Comment: Is using that particular function from psych a must? In other words, would using `group_by` and `summarise_at` from dplyr be an option?

Comment: Hm that would be fine, as long as I can get the same descriptives into a matrix!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use dplyr, with some custom functions added.

```
library(dplyr)

se <- function(x) sd(x, na.rm=TRUE)/sqrt(length(na.omit(x)))
rnge <- function(x) diff(range(x, na.rm=TRUE))

group_by(df, Time, Cohort, Gender) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(JL), .funs=list(n=length, mean=mean, sd=sd, min=min, max=max, range=rnge, se=se)) %>% 
  as.data.frame()
```

---

Using the mtcars dataset:

```
group_by(mtcars, vs, am, cyl) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(mpg), .funs=list(n=length, mean=mean, sd=sd, min=min, max=max, range=rnge, se=se)) %>% as.data.frame()

  vs am cyl  n mean    sd  min  max range    se
1  0  0   8 12 15.1 2.774 10.4 19.2   8.8 0.801
2  0  1   4  1 26.0    NA 26.0 26.0   0.0    NA
3  0  1   6  3 20.6 0.751 19.7 21.0   1.3 0.433
4  0  1   8  2 15.4 0.566 15.0 15.8   0.8 0.400
5  1  0   4  3 22.9 1.453 21.5 24.4   2.9 0.839
6  1  0   6  4 19.1 1.632 17.8 21.4   3.6 0.816
7  1  1   4  7 28.4 4.758 21.4 33.9  12.5 1.798
```

Using the `describBy` function from the psych package returns your error:

```
library(psych)
describeBy(mtcars$mpg, group=list(mtcars$vs, mtcars$am, mtcars$cyl), digits=3, skew=FALSE, mat=TRUE)
```

> Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, var, group + 1, value =
>   dim.names[[group]][[groupi]]) :    subscript out of bounds

Because not all combinations of the three groups exist in the data.

```
with(mtcars,
     ftable(table(vs,am,cyl)))
#      cyl  4  6  8
#vs am             
#0  0       0  0 12
#   1       1  3  2
#1  0       3  4  0
#   1       7  0  0
```

Comment: Thank you! This would work but I realized the problem is that one of the combination of the three groups is returning NA.

Comment: Not actually NA, more like MIA (missing in action).